# Create new columns based on other's columns value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do some feature engineering for a pandas data frame.

Say I have this:

```
Data frame 1:
X |  date     | is_holiday
a |  1/4/2018 | 0
a |  1/5/2018 | 0
a |  1/6/2018 | 1
a |  1/7/2018 | 0
a |  1/8/2018 | 0
...
b |  1/1/2018 | 1
```

I'd like to have an additional indicator for some dates, to indicate if the date is before 1 and 2 days from a holiday, and also 1 and 2 days after.

```
Data frame 1:
X |  date     | is_holiday | one_day_before_hol | ... | one_day_after_hol
a |  1/4/2018 | 0          | 0                  | ... | 0
a |  1/5/2018 | 0          | 1                  | ... | 0
a |  1/6/2018 | 1          | 0                  | ... | 0
a |  1/7/2018 | 0          | 0                  | ... | 1
a |  1/8/2018 | 0          | 0                  | ... | 0
...
b |  1/1/2018 | 1          | 0                  | ... | 0
```

Is there any efficient way to do it? I believe I can do it using for statements, but since I'm new to python, I'd like to see if there is an elegant way to do it. **Dates might not be adjacent or continuos (i.e. for some of the X columns, a specific date might not be present)**

Thank you so much!

Comment: Add the appropriate tag if this is related to pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.shift`:

```
import pandas as pd

g = df.groupby('X')['is_holiday']
df['one_day_before'] = g.shift(-1).fillna(0)
df['two_day_before'] = g.shift(-2).fillna(0)
df['one_day_after'] = g.shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   X      date  is_holiday  one_day_before  two_day_before  one_day_after
0  a  1/4/2018           0             0.0             1.0            0.0
1  a  1/5/2018           0             1.0             0.0            0.0
2  a  1/6/2018           1             0.0             0.0            0.0
3  a  1/7/2018           0             0.0             0.0            1.0
4  a  1/8/2018           0             0.0             0.0            0.0
5  b  1/1/2018           1             0.0             0.0            0.0
```

Comment: Thank you Chris! I believe this assumes that all dates are continuos? (Say index 1 is missing in the dataset, it wouldnt work?). Thank you!

Comment: @F_M Yes, indeed, in addition to assuming the `date` is sorted. Otherwise, you will have to modify the `date` column first before doing the `groupby` operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could shift:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,0,0,1,1,0], columns=['day'])
d.head()

   day
0   1
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1

df['Once Day Before'] = d['day'].shift(-1)
df['One Day After'] = df['day'].shift(1)
df['Two Days before'] = df['day'].shift(-2)

df.head()

day Holiday   One Day Before    One Day After   Two Days before
0     1            0.0               NaN              0.0
1     0            0.0               1.0              1.0
2     0            1.0               0.0              1.0
3     1            1.0               0.0              0.0
4     1            0.0               1.0              NaN
5     0            NaN               1.0              NaN
```

This would move the is_holiday up or down and to a new column. You will have to deal with the NaN's though.

Comment: Thanks! it is great solution but it fails if the dates are not continuos